# non homogenous $c\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=-1-2y$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am  doing this question
[image]
As it can't be solved using separation of variables (my assumption according to what i did, after checking by substituting $w(y,t)=f(y)g(t)$ , and getting a term at last which is **not depending on only single variable**)

> 1. Did my assumption is right ?
> 2. So how to solve this equation, I am stuck ?

Comment: Start with solving the homogeneous PDE. You can't separate variables directly for a non-homogeneous PDE, it should be obvious. Note that whether or not an equation is separable also depends on the initial/boundary conditions. $$ $$ In general, since you appear to be asking several homework-type questions in a row, you should show more of your own work. If you didn't have the chance to learn the basic PDE theory, I would suggest you start with that and then move on to the exercises.

Comment: got it .... i got the link useful for it .. which can be solved for $p(x)=c , q(x)=0 , f(x,t)=1+2x , \alpha_1 =1 , \alpha_2=0 , \beta_1 = 1 , \beta_2=0$ in the link:

https://www.math.usm.edu/math/lambers/mat417/lecture7.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the non-homogeneous part, you can substitute another variable and another function.

First, we can substitute:

$$z=2y+1 $$

Which gives us:

$$4c w_{zz}-w_t+z=0$$

Then we introduce a new function:

$$w=v(z,t)-\frac{z^3}{24 c}$$

Substituting, we get:

$$4c v_{zz}-v_t=0$$

The boundary and initial conditions change in an obvious way, and the result is a separable equation for $v(z,t)$ which is easy enough to solve.

As a further hint, the conditions change to (if I didn't make a mistake somewhere):

$$v(0,t)=\frac{1}{24c}, \qquad v(2L+1,t)=\frac{(2L+1)^3}{24c}+4 \\ v(z,0)=\frac{z^3}{24c}+\Phi \left(\frac{z-1}{2} \right)$$

Comment: ohhhh yes....  how can we modify ? i feel .. the PDF link i attach is more understandable.. to me... as this involves more complex conditions...


Edited : nice i just see new boundary conditions

Comment: @learningstudent, of course, use whichever method you understand best. It's just not always a good idea to use the big guns for simple problems

Comment: thanks ... i solved with your method ... it is easier... no n terms... series ... only one pure answer i got

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate both sides with respect to $y$, to obtain $\displaystyle c \frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial y^4} = \frac{\partial^3 w}{\partial t \partial y^2}$. From here, we can swap order of differentiation and use the substitution $\displaystyle v = \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}$ to obtain $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$. Solving from here is not too difficult. For more information/help, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation - there is a list of solutions to well-known PDEs there.